# Difference between Remote Desktop Services vs Windows Terminal Server vs Remote Desktop Session Host

Tags: deployment, gpo, terminal-server

Could someone explain me the difference between them?

Furthermore I have heard that Windows Terminal Server can be used to deploy software to multiple computers in the network in an organisation by creating a GPO. Could someone give me the steps to do this as well?

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop Services is set of different roles that work together to provide VDI or remote app experience to the end user. It has following core architecture components:

1. RD web access -------------> web page that list available apps to access
2. RD gateway    -------------> allow & block traffic
3. RD connection broker ------> load balance traffic between session hosts
4. RD session hosts ----------> these are the servers where applications or VDI are run from

Window Terminal Services is same as RDS. Microsoft renamed it in 2008. Terminal server essential is session hosts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-is-now-remote-desktop-services

I am not sure about the GPO part